# Better way to rewrite these IF clauses?

Tags: php, if-statement

is there any way to efficiently re-write this ?
Thank you

```
<?php if ($row['website']) { ?>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.<?= $row['website']; ?>"><i class="icon icon_desktop"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($row['twitter']) { ?>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/<?= $row['twitter']; ?>"><i class="icon social_twitter"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>                      
<?php if ($row['facebook']) { ?>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/<?= $row['facebook']; ?>"><i class="icon social_facebook"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($row['linkedin']) { ?>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/<?= $row['linkedin']; ?>"><i class="icon social_linkedin"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($row['youtube']) { ?>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/<?= $row['youtube']; ?>"><i class="icon social_youtube"></i></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, as a first step you could fix the indentation of the code you posted above :-)

Comment: I hope your data in `$row` is sanitized or your site is about to be exploited by JavaScript code or something in your links. You probably want to use `htmlspecialchars()`. This is also necessary for chars like `&`. And what about websites that use HTTPS or do not start with `www.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

(Here I just put all keys into an array which I then filter with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). After this you can simply loop through all of the filtered keys)

```
<?php

    $keys = ["http://www." => "website", "http://www.twitter.com/" => "twitter", "http://www.facebook.com/" => "facebook", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/"=> "linkedin", "http://www.youtube.com/user/"=> "youtube"];
    $keys = array_filter($keys, function($v)use($row){return $row[$v];});

    foreach($keys as $k => $key)
        echo "<li><a target='_blank' href='" . $k . $row[$key] . "'><i class='icon icon_" . $key . "'></i></a></li>";

?>
```

**(extra)EDIT:**

For people with php versions under <5.4 (`echo phpversion();`):
<sub>And because we live in 2015, [get the current version of PHP right here right now!](http://php.net/downloads.php#v5.6.7)</sub>

```
$keys = array("http://www." => "website", "http://www.twitter.com/" => "twitter", "http://www.facebook.com/" => "facebook", "http://www.linkedin.com/in/"=> "linkedin", "http://www.youtube.com/user/"=> "youtube");
function filter($v){global $row; return $row[$v];}
$keys = array_filter($keys, "filter");

foreach($keys as $k => $key)
    echo "<li><a target='_blank' href='" . $k . $row[$key] . "'><i class='icon icon_" . $key . "'></i></a></li>";
```

example output:

```
<li><a target='_blank' href='http://www.twitter.com/a'><i class='icon icon_twitter'></i></a></li>
<li><a target='_blank' href='http://www.linkedin.com/b'><i class='icon icon_linkedin'></i></a></li>
<li><a target='_blank' href='http://www.youtube.com/c'><i class='icon icon_youtube'></i></a></li>
```

Comment: "website" is slightly different than the rest.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Thanks for the notice, didn't saw it. updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for this but I got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' `

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos That means your php version is <5.4 (`echo phpversion();`) So you can't use this syntax. Then this should work for you: http://pastebin.com/hELrKPXT

Comment: thank you for the update, no errors found, but it seems that is not working

Comment: @Rizier123: Don't put the code off-site. Post it here please.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos The code works fine for me! Have you checked the source code from the output? Also do you only want to check if they contain a true value in it? (Maybe Put some text between the i tags?!)

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Ah just saw that I missed something with the url base, updated my answer. Now it should be all correct

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Works fine for me! https://eval.in/308529 What is the output of `var_dump($row);` ?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Also make sure you show us your **real** and **full** code. Also make sure you **current code works**

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos And where are we with this question? At the end in the middle? solved? ^^ See my last 2 comments

Comment: @Rizier123 yes it was solved. Thank you for the guidance, I forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not shorter, but easier to read and maintain in my eyes:

```
<?php 
foreach (array('website', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'linkedin', 'youtube') as $site) { 
    if ($row[$site]) {
        switch($site) {
            case 'website':  
                $urlBase = 'http://www.';
                $icon = 'icon_desktop'; 
                break;
            case 'twitter':  
                $urlBase = 'http://www.twitter.com/';  
                $icon = 'social_twitter'; 
                break;
            case 'facebook': 
                $urlBase = 'http://www.facebook.com/'; 
                $icon = 'social_facebook'; 
                break;
            case 'linkedin': 
                $urlBase = 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/'; 
                $icon = 'social_linkedin'; 
                break;
            case 'youtube':  
                $urlBase = 'http://www.youtube.com/user/';  
                $icon = 'social_youtube'; 
                break;
        }
        echo sprintf('<li><a target="_blank" href="%s%s"><i class="icon %s"></i></a></li>'."\n", $urlBase, $row[$site], $icon);
    }
}
?>
```

Often explicit is better than implicit when it comes to robustness and maintainability.